# How risize a thumbnail?

Tags: post-thumbnails, images

I have a wordpress thumbnail, but i when set the size this (500,200) wordpress resize the imagen and let it square, only 500x500.

I set in functions.php

```
add_image_size ('single_post',500,200)
```

In the theme

```
       if(has_post_thumbnail())  {
            the_post_thumbnail('single_post');
        }
```

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

You should define [`add_image_size`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size) with fourth parameter to allow WordPress to crop your image to exact size.

```
add_image_size ( 'single_post', 500, 200, true);
```

Whether to crop images to specified height and width or resize Difference between soft and hard crop

1. false - Soft proportional crop mode.
2. true - Hard crop mode.
3. array - Specify positioning of the crop area (x_crop_position, y_crop_position).

**Default: false**